# How do I get the length of a BucketListResultSet

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

Using boto.S3, what is the best way to get the total length of a BucketListResultSet? Do I really need to iterate through all of it?

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection('XXX', 'YYYY')

bucket = conn.get_bucket('myBucket')

l = bucket.list('just/a/prefix/')
```

Here, `l` is a [BucketListResultSet](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.0/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucketlistresultset.BucketListResultSet). How can I get the total number of objects in `l`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BucketListResultSet` is a generator that handles any pagination for you behind the scenes.  So, the only way to get the "length" of it would be to actually iterate over all of the results.  One simple way to do that would be to use `list(l)` in your example.  Note that this will be an expensive operation since it involves at least one (and possibly many) round trips to the S3 service.

Comment: I just tried the list(l) method using boto with a RadosGateway to OpenStack CEPH. This generator seems to fail even using list (bucket.list(...))

Comment: What kind of failure are you seeing?

Comment: The length of the result set varies.